# Is W a subspace for $R^2$?

Tags: vector-spaces

Given $V=R^2$ 
and $W=\{(x,y) \in R^2|x+y+5=5\}$ 
Is $W$ a subspace for $V=R^2$? 
I solved this by the condition $au+v \in W$ where $u,v \in W$ and $a \in F.$
If $u=(x_1,y_1) \ \text{and} \ v=(x_2,y_2)$ then 
\begin{align*}
a(x_1,y_1)+(x_2,y_2)& =(ax_1+x_2,ay_1+y_2) \\
&=(ax_1+x_2+ay_1+y_2+5) \\
&=(ax_1+ay_1)+(x_2+y_2+5) \\
&=ax_1+ay_1+5 \\
&=0+5=5
\end{align*}
Is this correct? Thanks in advance..

Comment: Note that $W=\lbrace (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2|x+y=0\rbrace=\langle (1,-1)\rangle$

Comment: Was being stupid. Lol. No I wasnt speaking to you

Answer (score 1):

The idea is alright, but it's not written correctly; for example in the red section

> \begin{align*}
> a(x_1,y_1)+(x_2,y_2)& =\color{red}{(ax_1+x_2,ay_1+y_2)} \\
> &\color{red}{=(ax_1+x_2+ay_1+y_2+5)} \\
> &=(ax_1+ay_1)+(x_2+y_2+5) \\
> &=ax_1+ay_1+5 \\
> &=0+5=5
> \end{align*}

you have an equality between a couple, an element of $\mathbb{R}^2$, and a real number...?

You want to check whether $(ax_1+x_2,ay_1+y_2) \in W$ so calculate the sum of the coordinates and verify if it simplifies to $5$:
$$(ax_1+x_2) + (ay_1+y_2) = \ldots$$

---

I would note that $x+y+5=5$ is equivalent to $x+y=0$, which is easier to work with.